# iterate through pandas rows and multiply by preset row (k-means)

Tags: python, pandas, k-means

I'm working on recreating k-means analysis with a preset dataframe. At the moment, I'm trying to iterate through each row of my dataframe (698 rows) and perform the function (row-mu)**2, then determine square root. The following step is to compare the square root of said function to the means of my 2 clusters (mu2 or mu4) to determine distance from that point, and assign that sqrt number to each classifier based on which it's closer to.. If I designate which rows will be my two mu parameters to operate on, my function works fine:

```
A=[]
B=[]

mu2=df1.loc[5] #in this instance, mu2=(8,10,10,8,7,10,9,7,1)
mu4=df1.loc[245] #in this instance, mu4=(5,1,1,2,2,2,3,1,1)
specificrow=df1.loc[374] #in this instance, specificrow=(3,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1)

def d(row, mu):
    sums=(row-mu)**2
    return math.sqrt(sums.sum())

mu2dist=d(specificrow, mu2)
mu4dist=d(specificrow, mu4)

if mu4dist<mu2dist:
    A.append(mu2dist)
else:
    B.append(mu4dist)

print(A, B)
```

This properly adds 20.25 to A

However, if I try assign mu2 and mu4 to random rows within the dataframe:

```
mu2=df1.ix[np.random.choice(df.index, 1)]
mu4=df1.ix[np.random.choice(df.index, 1)]
```

the same code doesn't work

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():  
    mu2dist=d(row, mu2)
    mu4dist=d(row, mu4)

    if mu4dist<mu2dist:
        A.append(mu2dist)
    else:
        B.append(mu4dist)

print(A, B)
```

I get an error that says:

```
'TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>'
```

the traceback also references my d(row, mu) function, this line in particular:

```
return math.sqrt(sums.sum())
```

I tried converting the entire df to float beforehand using .astype(), but I'm still getting that same error.

if I print mu2 and it's type (it obviously changes each time), I get this output:

```
     A2   A3   A4   A5   A6   A7   A8   A9  A10
28  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  1.0 <class 
'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

which appears to be float, but the actual type is simply 'pandas dataframe'. If anyone could steer me in the right direction for getting these amounts to return/print out, I'd be most appreciative. I still need to work on how I retain these values to reuse as I repeat this process many times to find the optimal centroids, but I need to get those values first.

Thanks

Comment: Try using `numpy.sqrt` instead.

Comment: well, that seemed to push the needle a bit, but now I get this error: